# Update Ugly Object Keys Using Another Array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Below array is called Data, it's array of objects with keys like "marketValue"

[image]

Below array is called Columns, it's array of objects with each has Header (Pretty name for columns) and id (Ugly name for columns)

[image]

How to scroll through Data and update all ugly keys like this "marketValue" to "Market Value" using columns array?

This is how far I got, but it doesn't work, it returns undefined for every singe row:

```
 let PrettyData = Data.map((row) =>
    Object.entries(row).forEach(
      (key) => {
        let newKey = columns.filter((colRow) => colRow.id === key[0]);
        let obj = {newKey: key[1]}
        return obj;
      }
    )
  );
```

Comment: `forEach` is not meant to return anything. In fact, it doesn't return `obj`. If you're planning to **alter** the `row` object, you should not `map` it. `map` method is meant to be used with a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the the keys of each object in data with the Header value of that columns object.  This should do it:

```
const prettyMapping = {};
columns.forEach((column)=>{
    prettyMapping[column.id] = column.Header
});
const PrettyData = Data.map((row)=>{
    const prettyRow = {};
    Object.keys(row).forEach((column)=>{
        prettyRow[prettyMapping[column]] = row[column]
    });
    return prettyRow
});
```

1. Go through the columns and create a mapping of header to id.
2. Map over the rows. Map will create a new array with whatever is returned from each original row iteration
3. In each row iteration, create the newly formatted row using our mapping from before.

For this case:

```
const Data = [{qty:1, mp:2}, {qty:1, mp:2, mv:2}];
const columns = [{id:"qty",Header:'Quantity'}, {id:"mv",Header:'Market Value'}, {id:"mp",Header:'Market Price'}]
```

The above code returns:

```
[ { Quantity: 1, 'Market Price': 2 },
  { Quantity: 1, 'Market Price': 2, 'Market Value': 2 } ]
```

Hope this helps!